# Django model TypeError at /writeReview/1 __str__ returned non-string (type int)

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am facing issues related to the above error (also shown in picture 4). Can someone help me out here? I am seeing this error while trying to submit the form which saves the data to the ReviewTable as shown in the picture 2. I have also added the code below:

````
    TypeError at /writeReview/1

    __str__ returned non-string (type int)

    Request Method:     GET
    Request URL:    http://55fde5117b01476bb57eb987ae0e9a37.vfs.cloud9.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/writeReview/1?csrfmiddlewaretoken=yJ0M6sDxPjEZJmJxrR0JMLFYJzboppJ6NGfa5H25D7ieDNTVQKIy9pFhu9WKYsDA&reviewText=This+is+a+test+&rating=2
    Django Version:     3.0.2
    Exception Type:     TypeError
    Exception Value:    

    __str__ returned non-string (type int)

    Exception Location:     /home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py in __repr__, line 518
    Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python36
    Python Version:     3.6.10
    Python Path:    

    ['/home/ec2-user/environment/HangryBirds',
     '/usr/lib64/python3.6',
     '/usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload',
     '/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
     '/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages',
     '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
     '/usr/lib64/python3.6/dist-packages',
     '/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages']

    Server time:    Thu, 2 Apr 2020 16:44:16 +0000
    Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

        /home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py in get_prep_value

                        return int(value)

             …
        ▶ Local vars
        During handling of the above exception (int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'RestaurantTable'), another exception occurred:
        /home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py in inner

                        response = get_response(request)

             …
        ▶ Local vars
        /home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response

                            response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

             …
        ▶ Local vars
        /home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response

                            response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

             …
        ▶ Local vars
        /home/ec2-user/environment/HangryBirds/home/views.py in writeReview

                    newReview.save()

         ```


Views.py[1]
Here's the views.py file where the form data is saved to the ReviewTable in models.py
````

````
def writeReview(request, parameter):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        newReview = ReviewTable()
        username = request.session['username']
        newReview.review = request.GET['reviewText']
        newReview.rating = request.GET['rating']
        newReview.timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
        newReview.userObj_id = UserTable.objects.filter(username=username)
        newReview.menuObj_id = parameter
        newReview.restObj_id = MenuTable.objects.filter(item_ID=parameter).first().restObj
        newReview.save()
        template = loader.get_template("showReview.html")
        return HttpResponse(template.render())

    else:
        template = loader.get_template("home.html")
        return HttpResponse(template.render())```
````

Models.py[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xuR6.png)
Here's the schema of the ReviewTable:-

````
    class ReviewTable(models.Model):
        userObj = models.ForeignKey(UserTable, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        menuObj = models.ForeignKey(MenuTable, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        restObj = models.ForeignKey(RestaurantTable, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        review = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
        timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=True)
        rating = models.IntegerField()

        def __str__(self):
            return self.id```

    ShowReview.html[3]
Here's the html form section where the data is transfered to views.py for saving to the table.
    ```<div class="right-template">
                {% for m in menu_ID %}
                    <h2>{{ m.item_name }}</h2>
                    <h2>Reviews</h2>
                    {% for r in review_ID %}
                        {% if r.menuObj_id == m.item_ID %}
                            <h4>{{ r.userObj.username }}</h4>
                            <p>{{ r.review }}</p>
                            <p>{{ r.timestamp }}</p>
                            <p>{{ r.rating }}</p>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                     <h2>Write a Review</h2>
                     {% block content %}
                        <form method="GET" action="{% url 'writeReview' parameter=m.item_ID %}" >
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <div>
                                <textarea id="reviewText" name="reviewText" rows="5" cols="50" max_length="900"></textarea>
                                <label for="rating">Rating</label>
                                <input type="number" name="rating" max_length="5" id=rating>
                                <button type="submit" class="btnRest">Submit</a>
                            </div>    
                        </form>
                    {% endblock %}
                  {% endfor %}
````

Error pic[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bA8JI.png)

Comment: You should show the code in your question instead of using pictures, it makes it easier for people to help.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode I did not dv, but please copy the code in the question, *not images* of code.

Comment: @X18PY Take a look now. Sorry my bad for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

As the exception says, a `__str__` is supposed to return a *string*. `self.id`, is an `int`, not a string. You can use `str(..)` to convert the int to a string:

```
class ReviewTable(models.Model):
    # …

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

Note that in your view, you should either use `.newReview.restObj = restaurant_object`, or `.newReview.restObj_id = id_of_restaurant_object`:

```
def writeReview(request, parameter):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        newReview = ReviewTable()
        username = request.session['username']
        newReview.review = request.GET['reviewText']
        newReview.rating = request.GET['rating']
        newReview.timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
        newReview.userObj = UserTable.objects.get(username=username)
        newReview.menuObj_id = parameter
        newReview.restObj = MenuTable.objects.first(item_ID=parameter).restObj
        newReview.save()
        template = loader.get_template("showReview.html")
        return HttpResponse(template.render())

    else:
        template = loader.get_template("home.html")
        return HttpResponse(template.render())
```

> **Note**: A GET request is *not* supposed to have *side-effects*, hence constructing
>   objects when a user makes a GET request, is not compliant with the HTTP
>   standard. Therefore it might be better to turn this into a POST request.

Comment: I tried that but it is not working. Do I have to make migrations after doing that change? However, on making that change and running the migration command I don't see any migrations required.

Comment: @HarshPatel: no this does not require a migration. Did you make other models where you returned the `self.id` instead of `str(self.id)`?

Comment: No, I haven't used str anywhere in the other models. I have used self.id everywhere in the other models too.

Comment: @HarshPatel: furthermore you should assign either ids to the `field_id` field, or objects to the `field` field of  a `ForeignKey`, not mix the two.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get what you are implying. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: __str__(self)

Called by str(object) and the built-in functions format() and print() to compute the “informal” or nicely printable string representation of an object. The return value must be a string object.

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__

So his answer should be correct, remember that this applies to all of the __str__ that you use. It should always return a string.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem when I add this line:
```      
newReview.restObj = MenuTable.objects.first(item_ID=parameter).restObj
 ```
it shows the following error ```TypeError at /writeReview/1

first() got an unexpected keyword argument 'item_ID'

Request Method:  GET```

Comment: @HarshPatel: well that was already part of your code. Likely your `MenuTable` model has no `item_ID` field...

Comment: It is there. Take a look here:- 
```class MenuTable(models.Model):
    item_ID = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    restObj = models.ForeignKey(RestaurantTable, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.item_ID```